# Copying assembly from 'Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll' to 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll' failed UNITY3D error

Tags: unity-game-engine

[The image shows the error in the editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5oWZ.png)This error is appearing in a completely new project, before I have made any changes. This is the error I keep receiving in the Unity Editor. I have updated Unity to the latest version - 2019.1.9.f1. I am unable to use Unity because of this error. Based on other threads talking about this topic, I have tried their suggestions like :

1. "Reimporting all scripts".
2. Clearing the "Temp" folder.
3. "Reset packages to default" option.
4. Made exceptions in the antivirus. Also tried by removing the antivirus completely.
5. Made changes to the project and saved it. Then reopened the project, but the error was still there.

All these suggestions could not help me solve the error. I am unable to build anything. My projects have come to a standstill.

ALSO, I had been receiving the same error for textmeshpro also. I resolved that by uninstalling the package. It's related, but I can't find the issue.

I am a bit desperate, and would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: You could try to (force) delete Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll and/or Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll and let Unity recompile

Comment: I checked, and I could not locate the Assembly-CSharp.dll file anywhere in the project. I checked in the Temp folder as well as the ScriptAssemblies folder.

Comment: I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and installed Visual Studio 2019, just to check. Error still persists every time I open a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was working and all my projects had come to a standstill. The only way out, which I thought was resetting my windows(removing everything except my personal files). That did the trick. Although I may need to install my games from steam once again, at least Unity works fine!

Comment: Oww boy I am just after repairing a heavy BSoD issue on this PC and in no way I will be resetting the system or anything again, there must be easier solution.